# Javascript document.getElementByID(...) is NULL

Tags: javascript, html

i got a problem in Javascript.
i want to set a value from text input to a specific value, when clicking a link.

```
<form method="get" action="db.php">
<dl>
    <dt>
        Part:
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="text" name="part"></input>
    </dd>
....
....  
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('part').value = 'motor';">motor</a>
```

but the

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

error appear

whats wrong with it?

Comment: Do you see an id in any of your HTML??

Answer (score 3):

`getElementById` find an element by `id`. There is no elementi with `id` `=` `part` in your dom sample. That's why it returns null. You could use [`document.getElementsByName(string)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) and it would return the array with the elemtns with the name specified, in your could, the `0` index get the `input` tag!

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementsByName('part')[0].value = 'motor';">motor</a>
```

It will return and `array`, so get the first element. Would be nice if you check it on a function if you get some result and apply the `value` property.

Comment: FYI: It's `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName`, Will return HTML Collection :) So `onClick="document.getElementsByName('part')[0].value`

Answer (score 2):

simply add id to input tag and then you could use getElementById('part')

```
<input type="text" name="part" id="part"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` has a NAME of "part", not an ID. Therefor, there is no element on the page with an ID of "part", which is why you get a null result.